# Virtuemart multilingual

Tags: joomla, multilingual, virtuemart

I started to work in a company where I need to edit some articles on Joomla website with VirtueMart. I have one problem:

1. The Website has 4 languages, problem is that when I try to edit an article only the English version is updated; I can't figure out why.
   I already tried to search on google but I didn't provide any answers.

What could be wrong?

If anyone has any solution I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have all your languages in admin panel - extensions - language manager - content languages.
2. Your virtuemart should have tables with postfix _en_GB or _ru_RU or something else (duplicate VM tables for every language)
3. For edit article Joomla or article VM (with extensions) your should have buttons "changes language flags" for every language.
4. For article Joomla your should create new post (article) for every language. Example: you have aaa (eng). Your menu link "Link 1" looks at "aaa" article (eng). You should create new article for other language and create new menu for this language. And create new module for this language and publsihed this in your site. Attention! You menu should be displayed only selected language (for eng article - eng menu, for rus article - rus menu etc.)

I hope I can help you...